# How I can disable\hide UI Eclipse action-bar buttons by code?

Tags: java, eclipse

For some plugin I need to disable\hide part of UI Eclipse's action-bar buttons by code.
Is no issue to add\remove buttons created by me but I cannot find the way how to influence on Eclipse buttons.

Comment: You can use 'Activities'. See "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Advanced workbench concepts > Filtering large user interfaces" in the Eclipse Help

Answer (score -1):

put `setUndecorated(true);` in your class constructor (just the one which extends JFrame)

Comment: This question is about the Eclipse UI which uses SWT, not Swing.